# Let's Encrypt : "renew" or not option

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I have currently the following script to generate certificates whose paths are in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/my_domain.com.conf` :

```
version = 0.15.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my_domain.com
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/fullchain.pem
```

I have for the moment generated these certificates 3 months ago.

The renewal is soon coming, so I have put the following script into `crontab` :

**Script :**

```
# cd letsencrypt
cd /root/letsencrypt/
# Generate all files
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a standalone -d my_domain.com --rsa-key-size 4096
```

**Crontab :**

```
0 3 25 3,6,9,12 * . /root/bin/renew_certificates > /dev/null 2>&1
```

However, I have seen the same command above but with in addition the "`renew`" option.

How can I be sure that my command is right for renewal? Is it necessary to add the "`renew`" option?

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the link !